# What is the best and very simple method to monitor table data changes in SQL Server from below list?

Tags: sql-server, database, monitoring

I am new to SQL  Server. I need to monitor TableData Changes in database. I  am using 2012 version SQL Server Management Studio.

If any insertions, deletions, modifications are done in SQL stored procedure, I need to send the stored procedure output result as parameter from SQL Server to a web service.

For Table Data monitoring, I am referred several articles from internet. I am found several concepts while searching in Google. I need to know, which concept is more effective for coding and very simple too.

**Methods:-**

1. Change Data Capture
2. Change Tracking
3. SQL Server Audit
4. Triggers
5. Output Clause
6. CLR  Triggers
7. Data Collector

From above 7 methods, which method is too effective and easy to use,  understand for TableData Monitoring  in SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Comment: Tell us a little more about what details of the change you want to log, do you want every column, datetime, user? Don't write to a web service, it'll slow you down and create transaction integrity issues.

Comment: My Requirement is ...Need to monitor the TableData Changes(Insertion,Deletions and Modifications of Old Data)  in SQL Server Database.If  any  Data Changes occur in TableData,the SQL Server need to send Instant Notifications from SQL Server Management Studio to WCF Service.  If  WCF  Service receives,instant notifications from SQL,the signalr in  wcf service,need to send instant messages of Data Modifications to all connected Clients!....   This is my Requirement.

Comment: Does "instant" mean "blocks the completion of the transaction making the modification"? That is, does the notification need to be synchronous or can it be asynchronous? If the latter, what is the amount of delay that's tolerable to your application?

Comment: I am Expecting minimum  2 minutes and maximum delay of 10 minutes to my application.here i am mentioned instant notification means messages should be received as  updated sequence.

Comment: That means no sync, otherwise you would be locking the DB for 10 minutes. And does this alerts need to take place for changes on any table in the DB or just one single table? Also, how often is this table changed?

Comment: i think i would skip the time sequence.now i am move to triggers. After update,after delete,after insert triggers..if any modifications done in existing data,the triggers event will fired. anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: If you only need to publish data you probably should be looking at change tracking using the Sync Framework. The most important thing might be to make sure the sync is outside of the transaction so that it doen'f hold things up. Just record that there has been a change with the trigger and let a separate process pick up the change and send it to the subscriber.