# How to automatically find out or get notified when a SQLServer's table data is modified

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, monitoring

I have come across some of the questions related to this topic in StackOverflow but most of them are not answered.
SQLServer,ASP.NET MVC are used.

I have multiple tables(T1,T2,T3,T4,T5) and When the data in tables T1,T2,T3,T4 is modified I have to update the time stamp in the table T5.
Ex: T2 is the country table which has information about all the countries 
    T3 is the Keyboard table which has all the parts description.
    T4 is TV screen table which has all the parts description.
    T1,T5 is the table which has information about the above tables, LookupName,DataAdded,DataModified.
(FirstRow will be Country,DateAdded,DateModified etc)
    T1 also have additional column like enable, which is N, then we will remove the corresponding entry in T5 table.

If any data in the T1,T2,T3,T4 is changed(from UI or directly from sqlserver), I have to update the corresponding row timestamp column in T5.

I need not monitor data changes on all the rows of the T1 table as it has row data which I need not track the changes.

I thought of using triggers, but I was told that it will hinder performance and my lead was not satisfied and he wanted to know anyway we can get a signal or a notification kind when data in the T1,T2,T3,T4 are modified.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Look at [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: are you using plain SQL in your queries or any ORM ?

Comment: @KD we use BLToolKit for ORM.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yeah, I am currently looking at SqlDependecy. Came across it in one of the similar questions. Thanks.

Comment: some of the threads got closed without proper answer like these. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342961/what-is-the-best-and-very-simple-method-to-monitor-table-data-changes-in-sql-ser)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen With SqlDependecy, Can I get notifications automatically whenever data in some of the tables get changed (from UI, directly modifiying data through management studio) or should I poll every time?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen SqlDependency is not giving information about the data changed. like the row data that has modified,added,deleted. Just getting notification of the type of change happened.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers can cause problems with performance if they are not carefully written and tested.  That said, triggers are a powerful tool, and should not be ruled out altogether.  This sort of pattern works well...

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_T1]
    ON [dbo].[T1] --Repeat this pattern for T2, T3 & T4
    FOR UPDATE NOT FOR REPLICATION
    AS
BEGIN;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE T5
        SET DataModified = GETDATE()
        FROM dbo.T5
            INNER JOIN DELETED
                ON T5.ID = DELETED.ID;
END;
```

I should stress the importance of **testing** this code (for performance and for behaviour) which I haven't done as I have no access to your data.  But hopefully you get the point?

Comment: I suggested this idea to my lead and he doesn't  wanted to use triggers at all. He wants some other alternative .

Comment: An alternative is to store the DataModified date against rows in T1, T2... T4.  You could then create a VIEW to UNION ALL and finally GROUP BY your Primary Key ID for T1.  Aggregate DataModified as required (E.g. MAX(DataModified).  Essentially calculate the dates on the fly.  This would negate need for TRIGGERs but obviously reading the dates would be slower.  What's more important?  Fast reads or fast writes?

Comment: I am sorry @NickAllan. Forgot to mention another thing, the T1 table which is a master table consists of other rows on which I need not track the data changes. So my lead asked not to add a DateColumn to the T1.

Comment: You might consider using "Change Tracking", which is a feature of SQL Server intended to deal with this sort of problem.  I've not had cause to use it before, however there is a lot of information available online.  E.g. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1819/using-change-tracking-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Thanks, will go through the link you provided.